# Express mounting routes

Tags: javascript, express

I am looking at some code from someone else for learning purposes. The way they're mounting routes is vague to me.

```
app.use('/dist', express.static(path.join(CURRENT_WORKING_DIR, 'dist')))

// mount routes
app.use('/', userRoutes)
app.use('/', authRoutes)
app.use('/', postRoutes)
```

The confusing part for me is how they're using '/' and using app.use. I'm used to doing it with app.get() and on top of that you specify the route instead of putting '/' everywhere. How does this work? Is this better practice?

The repo I'm looking at is https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-social/tree/master/server

Comment: just check `userRoutes` source, you will see that it's simple

Comment: Is this good practice? Looks like When landing on '/' it will have to check every route to see which one it needs. If you have like a lot of routes isnt it better to specify the routes at the beginning? @MedetTleukabiluly

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use, with https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router

Comment: quality of your code will not change if you use `use`, its just primarily opinion-based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing routes directly can be confusing and difficult to manage if there are large number of routes. So according to MVC pattern, the application is divided into modules/logical blocks based on functionalities they perform. For example, a simple hospital management system can have authentication, billing, payroll , medical-stock , patients etc modules (imaginary). If you are building application using MVC pattern, the common practice is to write controller for each of the module. Express provides something called **middleware** also called as **Router** to attach these controllers to respective API routes (Imagine it as a sort of map that connects each route to respective controller).

Once you define routes for each of these modules through middleware, you **use** those routes with your application. These routes handle requests and send parameters to controller to process. 
You can learn how to use Middleware and Routers here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_routing.htm

Regarding quality of code, dividing the code into modules and using routers to connect them is less tedious for others to understand. It also provides a good view of the application and it becomes easier to add new modules / functionality.

You can read more about building production-ready express app here :
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-write-a-production-ready-node-and-express-app-f214f0b17d8c/